# How to send an email to currently logged in user Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to set up a view so when the user visits the path /clip it will send an email to the user's inbox.

Eg. I visit path, email turns up in my inbox.

I am using this:

```py
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def clippy(request):
  current_user = request.user
  subject = "test"
  message = "testing"
  recipient_list = [current_user.email]
  send_mail(subject, message, recipient_list)
```

I'm using 3.0.4 and get this error when I visit the path:

```
send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'recipient_list'
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

**EDIT**: I have used the answer by reza heydari and it fixes this issue, now I get the following:

```
TypeError at /clip/
send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'from_email'
```

```py
@login_required()
def clippyemail(request):
  current_user = request.user
  subject  =  'Clippy here', 
  message = 'Hi! I am clippy! You resserected me somehow so thanks!',
  recipient_list =  [current_user.email,  ]
  send_mail(subject, message,  recipient_list=recipient_list)
```

is there any way I can set it up so it just sends the email using the SMTP settings in settings.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd arg of `send_mail` is `from_email` based on [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#send-mail)
Change your code like that:

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email="example@email.com", recipient_list=recipient_list)
```

And also add

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

For your local to recieve email in terminal

Comment: This helped! This is probably really obvious but now i'm getting: Exception Value: send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'from_email'. Then if I try to put from_email=None in the send_mail function then it says something about tuples. Any ideas?

Comment: update your question with new code and new error I will see

Comment: Updated the awnser

Comment: I want to send the email to the user using the SMTP settings defined in settings.py, is there a way this can be achieved using the same method?

Comment: Yes, if you config SMTP settings correctly it works.